# Add Marker on the polygons' centre using OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, vector, geometry

I have written a code to draw polygon from the WKT format. Now I need to add the marker at its centre. In the following code I have passed the centre and shape in WKT format(extracted from database).

```
function drawPolygon(id,shape,centre){
    var element = shape;
    var features = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT().read(element);
    features.geometry.transform(toProjection,fromProjection);
    var centre_poly = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT().read(centre);
    centre_poly.geometry.transform(toProjection,fromProjection);
    var featurePoint = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                centre_poly,{ 
                externalGraphic: 'img/map-marker.png', 
                graphicHeight: 25, 
                graphicWidth: 21, 
                graphicXOffset: -12, 
                graphicYOffset: -25 
                }
            );
    features.id=id;
    vectorLayer.addFeatures([features]);//working But only Polygon drawn
    vectorLayer.addFeatures([features,featurePoint]); //Not working

    }
```

Can anyone help me to point my mistake here or give any other alternative Solution?

Comment: Please do not [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422004/add-marker-on-the-polygons-centre). And, as I asked on SO, what is the error?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question on more than one site in the Stack Exchange network.  If you perceive a need to then review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234495/how-to-ask-the-same-question-on-different-sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenLayers has a GetCentroid function for getting the centre of a polygon if you don't want to bring it in from the database directly:

http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.getCentroid

From there you should just be able to treat the point as a regular point feature. See also this example:
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/icon.html?q=marker

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: geometry_from_GetCentroid,
  name: 'Null Island',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
})
```

Comment: OP's question relates to OL2. And he hasn't really made it clear what his issue is, other than not shifting the graphic by half its width and height, as has been suggested on the identical question posted on SO two days ago.

Comment: The problem is that the marker is not showing.And I have shifted the graphic @JohnBarça.See "graphicXOffset" and "graphicYOffset" in above question.

Comment: The problem was solved when I used getCentroid(). But I still don,t khnow what my mistake was.Anyway thanks GIS-Jonathan